# Why does requests.get not work on this domain?

Tags: python, web-scraping, centos, python-requests, cgi

```
import requests
url = ('https://rshl.org/ci/')
r = requests.get("%s" % url)
test = r.status_code

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<title>Hello Word First CGI Program</title>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '<h2>Status Code:%s</h2>' % test
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

Python 2.7.2 - CentOS returns an error page

Idle returns the correct value.

Does anyone know why this is occuring?

Comment: "returns an error page." okay... what does the error say? If you're new, please refer to this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `Idle returns the correct value.`. What does this mean ?

Comment: Anyways, running your example seems to work fine on my box. What happens if you visit that page from your browser? Do you get the same error? This might be a problem with your network rather than the code

Comment: Correct value in the sense that the html is printed with the 200 status code in idle Python GUI

Comment: @AndyCarlson No, in the browser the domain is reachable. It's only when running the script from the webserver.

Comment: `test` comes out 200 for me in 3.6. Not sure what your issue could be.

Comment: @PedrovonHertwig Ok, thank you if one more confirms i'll delete post. Thank you Pedro

Comment: it works for me but I checked it only once. If you run it many times then server may blocks you or sends page with warning or captcha so you could save `r.text` in file and open in browser to see what you get.